# Show command executed along with output in log file

Tags: shell-script, logs, io-redirection

Is there a quick and dirty way to not only log the output of a shell file but the commands used inside as well?

For example:

`whoami > who.dmp`

would output a file that contained something like:

`my_username`

For a longer shell file, what is the most effective way to display the command that caused the result in the log file as well

Ex:

```
log.txt
###############

echo whoami  <- I want this to show in the file as well
my_username

time   <- I want this to show in the file as well

real    0m0.00s
user    0m0.00s
sys     0m0.00s
```

Is there a way to do this without hard-coding exporting the command into the output file every single time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the shell built-in `set -x` is probably the cheap-and-dirty way to do this. In shell scripts you will often see a line like:

```
#set -x
```

Which someone left behind by just commenting it out.  I think you could use that at the interactive command line, but you may not like what it does there.

Comment: to disable it use `set +x`

Answer (score 3):

You could look into the `script` tool, which will save the entire terminal session until you exit the program you call (which by default would be a shell).  Example use-case:

```
~/:$ script test.output
Script started, output file is test.output
~/:$ mkdir example
~/:$ cd example
~/example/:$ touch new\ file.txt
~/example:/$ ls
new file.txt
~/example:/$ exit
```

The contents of the file `test.output` would then be as follows:

```
Script started on Mon Jun 25 16:24:28 2012
~/:$ mkdir example
~/:$ cd example
~/example/:$ touch new\ file.txt
~/example/:$ ls
new file.txt
~/example/:$ exit
```

Script done on Mon Jun 25 16:24:41 2012
Be aware that this file is a **complete** terminal transcript, so any backspaces will show up as `^H` or `^?` (or whatever your terminal's backspace is).